# Combining Two Spark Streams On Key

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have two kafka streams that contain results for two parallel operations, I need a way to combine both streams so I can process the results in a single spark transform. Is this possible? (illustration below)

```
Stream 1 {id:1,result1:True}
Stream 2 {id:1,result2:False}
       JOIN(Stream 1, Stream 2, On "id") -> Output Stream {id:1,result1:True,result2:False}
```

Current code that isn't working:

```
    kvs1 = KafkaUtils.createStream(sparkstreamingcontext, ZOOKEEPER, NAME+"_stream", {"test_join_1": 1})
    kvs2 = KafkaUtils.createStream(sparkstreamingcontext, ZOOKEEPER, NAME+"_stream", {"test_join_2": 1})

    messages_RDDstream1 = kvs1.map(lambda x: x[1])
    messages_RDDstream2 = kvs2.map(lambda x: x[1])

    messages_RDDstream_Final = messages_RDDstream1.join(messages_RDDstream2)
```

When I pass two sample jsons to each Kafka queue with the same ID field, nothing is returned in my final RDD stream. I imaging I am missing the stage of converting my Kafka JSON string message into a Tuple?

I have also tried the following:

```
kvs1.map(lambda (key, value): json.loads(value))
```

and

```
kvs1.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

To no avail

Cheers

Adam

Comment: Both of your RDDs only consist of keys, you need to have a PairRDD to use the `join` operation correctly with the following RDD structural type : `(key, value)`

Answer (score 3):

A simple lookup on Spark's documentation would have given you the answer..

You can use the `join` operation.

> **join**(otherStream, [numTasks]) :
>
> When called on two DStreams of (K, V) and (K, W) pairs, return a new DStream of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key.

For example : `val streamJoined = stream1.join(stream2)`

Comment: See my latest answer

Comment: Please add your research efforts to the original question for better visibility.

Comment: Updated my test code - I'm imagining its the map() that i am doing wrong as i need to do a JSON loads?

Answer (score 2):

What you need can be done using the `join()` method of key-value pair DStreams:

```
// Test data
val input1 = List((1, true), (2, false), (3, false), (4, true), (5, false))
val input2 = List((1, false), (2, false), (3, true), (4, true), (5, true))

val input1RDD = sc.parallelize(input1)
val input2RDD = sc.parallelize(input2)

import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))
// Creates a DStream from the test data
import scala.collection.mutable
val input1DStream = streamingContext.queueStream[(Int, Boolean)](mutable.Queue(input1RDD))
val input2DStream = streamingContext.queueStream[(Int, Boolean)](mutable.Queue(input2RDD))
// Join the two streams together by merging them into a single dstream
val joinedDStream = input1DStream.join(input2DStream)
// Print the result 
joinedDStream.print()
// Start the context, time out after one batch, and then stop it
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(5000)
streamingContext.stop()
```

Results in:

```
-------------------------------------------                                     
Time: 1468313607000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(4,(true,true))
(2,(false,false))
(1,(true,false))
(3,(false,true))
(5,(false,true))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have joined two queueStream using Spark java. Please have a look at below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

import com.google.common.collect.Queues;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class SparkQueueStreamJoin {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // Test data
    List<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> input1 = Arrays.asList(Pair.of(1,true), Pair.of(2,false), Pair.of(3,false), Pair.of(4,true), Pair.of(5,false));
    List<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> input2 = Arrays.asList(Pair.of(1,false), Pair.of(2,false), Pair.of(3,true), Pair.of(4,true), Pair.of(5,true));

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SparkQueueStreamJoin ")
            .set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000");
    //System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/H`enter code here`adoop/hadoop-2.7.1");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> input1RDD = sc.parallelize(input1);
    JavaRDD<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> input2RDD = sc.parallelize(input2);

    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(3));

    Queue<JavaRDD<Pair<Integer, Boolean>>> queue1RDD = Queues.newLinkedBlockingQueue();
    queue1RDD.add(input1RDD);
    Queue<JavaRDD<Pair<Integer, Boolean>>> queue2RDD = Queues.newLinkedBlockingQueue();
    queue2RDD.add(input2RDD);

    // Creates a DStream from the test data
    JavaInputDStream<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> input1DStream = streamingContext.queueStream(queue1RDD, false);
    JavaInputDStream<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> input2DStream = streamingContext.queueStream(queue2RDD, false);

    JavaPairDStream<Integer, Boolean> pair1DStream = input1DStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Pair<Integer, Boolean>, Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, Boolean> call(Pair<Integer, Boolean> rawEvent) throws Exception {

            return new Tuple2<>(rawEvent.getKey(), rawEvent.getValue());
        }
    });
    JavaPairDStream<Integer, Boolean> pair2DStream = input2DStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Pair<Integer, Boolean>, Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, Boolean> call(Pair<Integer, Boolean> rawEvent) throws Exception {

            return new Tuple2<>(rawEvent.getKey(), rawEvent.getValue());
        }
    });

    // Union two streams together by merging them into a single dstream
    //JavaDStream<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> joinedDStream =  input1DStream.union(input2DStream);

    // Join the two streams together by merging them into a single dstream
    JavaPairDStream<Integer, Tuple2<Boolean, Boolean>> joinedDStream =  pair1DStream.join(pair2DStream);
    // Print the result 
    joinedDStream.print();
    // Start the context, time out after one batch, and then stop it
    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(5000);
    streamingContext.stop();
}
}
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1511444352000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1,(true,false))
(2,(false,false))
(3,(false,true))
(4,(true,true))
(5,(false,true))
```