# how to combine two dstream using pyspark?

Tags: python, json, pyspark, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have this problem on pyspark which is this:

I should combine two dstream into one dstream but unfortunately I have not received any print.

This is my code:

```
    sc = SparkContext(appName="Sparkstreaming")
    spark = SparkSession(sc)
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    ssc = StreamingContext(sc,3)

    kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"localhost:2181","consumer-be-borsa",{"Be_borsa":1})
    kafka_stream1 = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"localhost:2181","consumer-be-teleborsa",{"Be_teleborsa":1})

    dstream = kafka_stream.map(lambda k, v: json.loads(v['id']))
    dstream1 = kafka_stream1.map(lambda k, v : json.loads(v['id']))

    # Join
    streamJoined = dstream.join(dstream1)

    streamJoined.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    time.sleep(100)

    ssc.stop()
```

These are the two JSON files that I consume:

```
{"id": "Be_20200330", "Date": "2020-03-30", "Name": "Be", "Hour": "15.49.24", "Last Price": "0,862", "Var%": "-1,93", "Last Value": "1.020"}

{"id": "Be_20200330", "Date": "2020-03-30", "Name": "Be", "Volatility": "2,352", "Value_at_risk": "5,471"}
```

The result I would like is this:

```
{"id": "Be_20200330", "Date": "2020-03-30", "Name": "Be","Hour": "15.49.24", "Last Price": "0,862", "Var%": "-1,93", "Last Value": "1.020", "Volatility": "2,352", "Value_at_risk": "5,471"}
```

How can i do using pyspark?

I also tried to see the solution of this link:[Combining Two Spark Streams On Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323808/combining-two-spark-streams-on-key) but it doesn't work. Thanks